# Mercurial "is inside nested repo" issue at commit

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I'm new with the Mercurial plugin for Eclipse.

Just realized I was using the *workspace* folder for my commits.
So I change the folder for the commits to the project folder.

Now when I try to commit I get the error :

```
 path 'FragmentsApp/bin/classes.dex' is inside nested repo 'FragmentsApp'
```

FragmentsApp is my project.

Guess I should remove/delete the previous commits on *workspace* to start commit with out problems but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Temporarily move `FragmentsApp` out of outer repo and delete the file from the outer repo, like `hg rm FragmentsApp/bin/classes.dex`

Comment: Actually I've filed a bug about that, but they decided not to fix it (yet): http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3580

Comment: how I remove this project out from the outer repo ? thank you

Comment: use explorer, select the folder, press `ctrl+x`, then choose where to move and press `ctrl+v`

Comment: oh ok, I thought I should do it from Eclipse.

Comment: no, you just "fool" mercurial and make it thinking there is no nested repo anymore. And after you fix the inconsistency in the outer one - you put the inner one back.

Comment: @zerkms guess I did something wrong again. Now I got a "HG status pending" message next to my project on Eclipse and _"An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing resource FragmentsApp...".
data/FragmentsApp/bin/AndroidManifest.xml.i@cc6aedb751e7: no match found!"_  error when i try to refresh.

Comment: oh :-S What actually did you do? And what is "try to refresh"? Stop using eclipse, open console and fix it as I said.

Comment: ok everything is working now. Removed project from the outer repo and delete any files left.
Also i delete the project from _/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects_ folder.  
Seems it was a bug like you said and couldn't fix it from inside Eclipse.

Comment: Updated mercurial bug link: https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3580